# Burp Suite Professional 1.7.22 using a lot memory - Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running Burp Suite Professional 1.7.22 on my Windows Server 2012 R2 X64 Datacenter. However even if no scan is running and I'm not proxying connections from a browser Burp still uses over 3500mb of RAM. Has anyone experienced this and managed to get RAM down?

I'm using the Windows 64-bit Install version of Burp Suite and not `.jar`.

[image]

Update:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: We are going to need to know more information.  You don't indicate which version of the runtime you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound Updated with Java runtime. If you need anything else just ask.

Comment: Have you tried to set the memory limits the program can use?